# jQuery Mobile, quais seus concorrentes mais próximos?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Estou utilizando o jQuery Mobile para a construção de um interação simples com um sistema local. Apesar que boas recomendações estou passando por problemas e tem alguns momentos que a aplicação do nada trava, não funciona e causa transtornos.

Além do jQuery Mobile existe algum Framework Html Responsivo para construção de sites que rodaram exclusivamente em celulares e tablet e porque são melhores que o jQuery Mobile tecnicamente falando ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando estava desenvolvendo um aplicativo com Phonegap tive o mesmo problema até que me aconselharam a não usar o jQuery mobile, então fui procurar outros *frameworks*. Eu encontrei vários, mas o que mais gostei foram [Lungo](http://lungo.tapquo.com/) e [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) por causa do desempenho.

Comment: Ajudou sim muito obrigada, me diz uma coisa se pode adicionar os problemas na sua resposta causados dando a entender as causas técnicas vividas por você?

Comment: Silas
Que problemas enfrentou?
Fale mais dos frameworks que gostou....

Answer (score 1):

Ja fiz alguns aplicativos usando Phonegap, na real nunca usei jQuery Mobile por "n" fatores, como eu trabalho com tempo resposta do que o usuário ver na tela, eu preferi eliminar alguns *frameworks* pois o tempo de resposta é lento.

Eu uso apenas *media queries* de acordo com o dispositivo, assim o tempo resposta fica mais rápido.

Se você quer ir mais além recomendo usar o [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), já tem muita coisa pronta e ajuda a desenvolver algo mais rápido.

Porem existem esse muitos bons também:

- [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/)

Espero ter ajudado